# Can I use append! on literal lists?

Tags: scheme

From my understanding, it is invalid to use `set-car!` or `set-cdr!` on a literal list.

```lisp
(define nums '(1 2 3))
(set-car! nums 10)  ; Invalid.
```

With this in mind, can I use literal lists as arguments to SRFI 1's [`append!`](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#append!) procedure? I am asking this because implementations of `append!` presumably use `set-cdr!` on all but the last argument given to `append!`. If `set-cdr!` is invalid on a literal list, then so is using `append!` on literal lists. Is my thinking correct?

What about using a literal list for the last argument given to `append!`?

Cases:

- `(append! (list 1) '(2 3))` — Is this valid?
- `(append! '(1) (list 2 3))` — Is this valid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Literal constants, such as `'(1 2 3)` are *immutable* which means that you're not allowed to modify any part of them.  The [description for `append!`](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#Miscellaneous) in [srfi/1](https://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/) says

> [...] it is allowed, but not required, to alter cons cells in the argument lists to construct the result list. The last argument is never altered; the result list shares structure with this parameter.

Thus the last argument may be a literal: none of the others may be.